# How do I modify the panUp function for Three.js orbit controls?

Tags: javascript, controls, three.js

I'm currently trying to modify the behavior of the panUp function for three.js' oribit controls.

The default behavior causes the camera to move up and down on the y axis, and I would like it to move in and out on the z axis. I would like it to behave the same way that the panLeft function does, but just for a different axis.

I've tried modifying the panOffset from:

```
panOffset.set( te[4], te[5], te[6] );
```

to:

```
panOffset.set( te[2], te[1], te[0] );
```

which kind of works to an extent, but seems to only allow the camera to move on the x and z axis, and not a combination of both. the panLeft function on the other hand seems to have no problem moving in any direction.

Comment: If you are using three.js r.60, the panUp function does not move the camera up and down on THE y-axis, but on the camera's y-axis, which is parallel to pixel space. Moving in and out on the camera's z-axis is the same as zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. I noticed that I had something sort of working by using

```
panOffset.set(te[8],te[9],te[10]);
```

but this was still causing the camera to move along the y axis. My goal was to only move along x and z, in order to allow the user to grab and pan a map around. The solution was to set y to 0. Should have seen that sooner!

```
panOffset.set(te[8],0,te[10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your solution close but not quite correct.  It's also not entirely clear what you are changing.  To get map panning to work as though you are dragging across the map, one way is to change a single line of source code within the **OrbitControls.js** file.

On line 116 (ish) you need to change this...

```
v.set( te[ 4 ], te[ 5 ], te[ 6 ] );
```

To this:

```
v.set( -te[ 8 ] * 2, 0, -te[ 10 ] * 2 );
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185074/three-js-orbitcontrols-js-pan-camera-parallel-to-ground-plane-like-google-e/26188674#26188674