# Three.js & OrbitControls.js - pan camera parallel to ground plane (like Google Earth)

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a simple Three.js demo that uses OrbitControls.js.

I'd like to change the behavior of panning in OrbitControls. Currently, when you pan the camera, it moves the camera in a plane that is perpendicular to the viewing direction. I'd like to change it so that the camera stays a constant distance from the ground plane and moves parallel to it. Google Earth uses a similar control setup.

Edit: I should have mentioned this detail in the first place, but I'd also like the point where you click and start dragging to remain directly under the cursor throughout the entire drag. There needs to be that solid connection between the mouse movement and what the user expects to happen on the screen. Otherwise, it feels as though I'm 'slipping' when I try to move around the scene.

Can someone give me a high-level explanation of how this might be done (with or without OrbitControls.js)?

Comment: Is your "ground plane" actually a plane (e.g. Flat, or does it have variable height)?

Comment: It's actually flat. It's just an infinite plane located at (0,0,0) with an up vector of (0,1,0).

Comment: Oh, so you just want to pan only in the world X/Z directions, maintaining the camera at a fixed Y position?

Comment: Correct. The Y position can only change if I rotate the camera around the target point, or if I dolly the camera toward the target point.

Comment: Hm. So if the user rotates the camera up towards sky and dollies upwards, and then pans---is the camera still only allowed to move in the X/Z plane?

Comment: Correct. But I'm not sure we have the same definition of 'rotate the camera.' When you rotate, the camera orbits around target point  (which is usually on the plane) and always turns to look at that target point.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @Justin?

Comment: @EnZo Yes, I posted and accepted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185074/three-js-orbitcontrols-js-pan-camera-parallel-to-ground-plane-like-google-e/26187860#26187860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the overview:

1. Store the mousedown event somewhere.
2. When the mouse moves, get the new mousedown event.
3. For each of those points, find the points on the plane where those clicks are located (You'll need to put the points into camera space, transform them into world space, then fire a ray from the camera through each point to find their intersections with the plane. [This page](http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html) explains the ray-plane intersection test).
4. Subtract the world-space start intersection point from the world-space end intersection point to get the offset.
5. Subtract that offset from the camera's target point and you're done!

In the case of OrbitControl.js, the camera always looks at the target point, and its position is relative to that point. So when you change the target, the camera moves with it. Since the target always lies on the plane, the camera moves parallel to that plane (as long as you're panning).

Answer (score 11):

EDIT: `OrbitControls` now supports panning parallel to the "ground plane", and it is the default.

To pan parallel to screen-space (the legacy behavior), set:

```
controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
```

Also available is `MapControls`, which has an API similar to that of Google Earth.

three.js r.94

Comment: I tried this out. It's close, but it seems as though the panUp is backwards. Also, I should have mentioned this, but I wanted the point where you click and drag to remain under the cursor during the entire drag. It makes for a more natural, tactile experience for the user. I actually came up with a working solution after I posted this question. Should I add that to my answer?

Comment: 1. The so-called "backwards" panning can be fixed with a sign flip, but you need to check the behavior under a variety of operating systems -- especially OSX. 2. This approach keeps the point approximately under the cursor when the view is straight down from above. When the view angle is acute, adjusting the pan distance by a factor of cos( view-angle ) may give the result you want.

Comment: @Shashank Post a question on SO or on https://discourse.threejs.org if you need help.

Comment: I got it working @WestLangley. My bad. If anything else comes up, I'll surely post a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago I was working on exactly this issue, i.e. adaptation of OrbitControls.js to map navigation.

- Here's [the code of MapControls.js](https://github.com/grey-eminence/3DIT/blob/master/js/controls/MapControls.js).
- Here's [the demo](http://3dit.bordeaux.inria.fr/testbed.html#navigation_Map_Navigation) of the controls.

Comment: this looks perfect, but no longer works with version 75. The projection stuff has been deprecated and is causing an error.

Answer (score 2):

You should set your camera 'up' to z axe:

`camera.up.set(0,0,1)`

And then, the main problem with OrbitControl is its panUp() function. It should be fixed.

My pull request : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/12727

y axe is relative to camera axes and should be relative to a fixed plan in the world. To define the expected y axe, make a 90° rotation of camera x axe, based on world z axe.

```
v.setFromMatrixColumn( objectMatrix, 0 ); // get X column of objectMatrix
v.applyAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ), Math.PI / 2 );
v.multiplyScalar( distance );
panOffset.add( v )
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It seems `MapControls` work perfectly, but yeah, you need to use `camera.up.set(0, 0, 1)` if you want to use Z as the vertical axis and X-Y as the horizontal plane when panning. Thanks! ^^