# THREE.js: OrbitControls pan in z axis with PerspectiveCamera

Tags: three.js

I am using the [OrbitControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) class and I am trying to replace the panUp function by panFront. My objective is to move the camera along the z axis.

I did the following change but seems that it doesn't work:

```
var panFront = function() {

    var v = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function panFront( distance, objectMatrix ) {

        v.setFromMatrixColumn( objectMatrix, 2 ); // get Z column of objectMatrix
        v.multiplyScalar( distance );

        panOffset.add( v );
    };

}();
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185074/three-js-orbitcontrols-js-pan-camera-parallel-to-ground-plane-like-google-e/26188674#26188674

Comment: Yes it seems the same problem, I have found the solution that worked fro me, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

**Edited**

Set `v.y = 0;` to secure the pan only in xz axis.

```
var panFront = function() {

    let v = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function panFront( distance, objectMatrix ) {

        v.setFromMatrixColumn( objectMatrix, 2 ); // get Z column of objectMatrix
        v.y = 0;

        v.multiplyScalar( -distance );

        panOffset.add( v );
    };

}();
```

I set the x and y components to 0.

Comment: The purpose of the closure is to avoid instantiating new `Vector3` instances which must be garbage-collected. You are creating two instances each call.

Comment: Now, `v` should be normalized to have unit length, since it is a direction. Use the math in the answer I linked to above for consistent results.